# Debugging CSS (Possibly JavaScript or JQuery) Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

Issue: I have problems with this page: http://kivusandcamera.com/blog/ The page loads with a proper layout, but then the two blog entries "jump" to the left behind the navigation bar. I have spent a good bit of time trying work through the various CSS, inspecting it with developer tools, etc..., but I have reached a point where I feel like I need some help. Any advice would be appreciated.

Background: This is just a basic Wordpress theme that I am trying to customize for a website, so I am not 100% sure how

Additional Information: Though I am passingly familiar with CSS, I have done hardly any work involving responsive design, media queries, etc... Basically, I am saying (1) I would not be surprised if it is something really simple that I am missing, and (2) if something could be done a better way, please feel free to let me know.

UPDATE - It looks like this issue might be Javascript or JQuery related. Basically, a style attribute is getting injected into one of the div tags. The style attribute used an absolute position, with a certain width, and I have no idea how to modify it.

UPDATE #2 - It appears the issue happens with any pages I set in the theme to "Full Width" (see also the http://kivusandcamera.com/about page.) I think those pages must get processed differently by JS layout framework that is used. Again, I still haven't figured out how that is all happening.

Comment: If you disable javascript, then the posts don't jump, so it's definitely something that happens after page loads.

Comment: Hi, it seems, the posts are going to the left side and behind left nav sidebar, so there is an error with class'.ef-post.ef-no-thumbnail', you need to remove the position absolute property.

Comment: Great, that was kind of what I was afraid of. That position absolute property is added in a manner I am not quite sure I understand. In the PHP template, it reads:

- <article class="ef-post<?php echo !has_post_thumbnail() ? ' ef-no-thumbnail' : ''; ?>">

but then it comes out having that whole style tag added to it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there were two separate issues:

(1) The JQuery auto-layout framework was resizing the various page columns with the assumption that the navigation bar was the same size as the individual columns of blog entries. That caused an issue that had to be solved.

(2) The full page CSS had to be updated to reflect the lack of a resizing navigation bar.

Ultimately, these issues were very specific to the this particular Wordpress theme, so I doubt full description of the solution would provide much of a benefit to the community. Thank you to everyone who helped lead me to the solution.